# What is wrong with this postgresql query to set datestyle?

Tags: postgresql

```
alter database CST_SCRI1 set datestyle  to "ISO, DMY"
```

> ERROR:  database **cst_scri1** does not exist;

And this was the list of databases i have

```
"postgres"
"testdb"
"satish_caliber"
"satish_ajax"
"CST_Billing"
"caliber_ehcrms"
"satish_hcrms"
"Caliber_eCALIBRA"
"cst_scri"
"school"
"CST_SCRI1"
```

Comment: It's not an update query, that's the problem.

Comment: Put double quotes around your database name.

Comment: update your question write your update query here

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it in this way:

```
alter database "CST_SCRI1" set datestyle to "ISO, DMY"
```

And restart postgres:

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL "folds" identifiers (names of tables, columns, databases, etc) to lower-case by default. So although you typed `CST_SCRI1`, this gets folded to `cst_scri1`. Since your database was actually created with the name in uppercase, there is no database with that lowercase name, as the error says.

The solution is to put the identifier in `"double quotes"`, which suppresses the case folding.

It's generally sensible to *avoid uppercase letters in identifiers* when you're creating databases, tables, etc, so that you don't have to worry about this.